# Why is $\mathbb{R}^2$ endowed with the taxicab metric isomorphic to the infinity distance model of the cartesian real plane? (Hartshorne exercise 8.9)

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, affine-geometry, axiomatic-geometry

My question deals with the following exercise from Hartshorne's *Euclid: Geometry and Beyond*:

> *Following our general principles, we say that two models $M,M'$ of our geometry are **isomorphic** if there exists a 1-to-1 mapping $\phi:M\to M'$ of the set of points of $M$ onto the set of points $M'$, written $\phi(A) = A'$, that sends lines to lines, preserves betweenness, i.e., $A\ast B\ast C$ in M $\iff$ $A'\ast B'\ast C'$ in M', and preserves congruence of line segments, i.e., $AB\cong CD$ in M$ \iff$ $A'B'\cong C'D'$ in $M'$*

If $A=(a_1,a_2),B=(b_1,b_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2$, the exercise asks you to first show that $\mathbb{R}^2$ endowed with the *taxicab metric*:
$$d(A,B)=|a_1-b_1|+|a_2-b_2|$$
Is isomorphic to the model of $\mathbb{R}^2$ endowed with the *infinity distance*:
$$d(A,B)=sup\{|a_1-b_1|,|a_2-b_2|\}$$
How can we proceed in order to prove these models are isomorphic? How should we describe our isomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$? I'm definitely having trouble with sending congruent lines to congruent lines.

The second part of the exercise claims that the *taxicab metric model* is not isomorphic to that of the *standard model*, i.e., the cartesian plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ equipped with the usual *Euclidean distance*. Hartshorne leaves a hint to this exercise: in order to prove two models are not isomorphic, one just has to find a statement which is true in one model but not in the other. I'm thinking, for example, that the line:
$$y=x+1$$
Cuts the circle of center the origin $(0,0)$, and radius $1$ in infinitely many points in the *taxicab metric model*, a property that never holds in the *standard model*, which should make it clear that both models are not isomorphic. However, the first part still puzzles me, and I can't imagine how to proceed.

Thanks in advance for your time, any comments will be appreciated.

Comment: Drawing circles in the two models might give you a hint of why they are isomorphic.